# Resize Visuals in PowerBI using buttons and bookmarks

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two visuals in the report stacked on top of each other
by default, both of the visuals occupy 50% of the space.
I want functionality like 2 buttons to focus on each visual.

Now, when I click on the 1st button it should make the 1st visual 3 times the size of the 2nd visual. Similarly, when I click on the 2nd button it should make the 2nd visual 3 times the size of the 1st visual.

How to achieve this in Power BI. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thank you, Marked as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different visuals where if you select the data it will just be highlighted.
As of now we could see that is not supported by Power Bi, if you are using the visuals then you have to adjust it prior you publish your Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does not currently support dynamic resizing of visuals. But you can achieve this by using two versions of the same result by mutually using the visibility function.